# Means of Continuous Data-Sets

Tags: integration, statistics

I recently derived a theorem for finding the mean for data that isn't countable, and used it to show that the mean radius of a square is (2/π)arsinh(1) (≃ 0.561) times its side length.  However I can't find anything of the sort online.  Does this exist under some other name, or am I perhaps just being naive here?  Thanks!!

Comment: How do you define the mean radius of a square? Is that the average distance from the center of the square to a randomly selected point in the square?

Comment: @grand_chat Yes, a random point on its perimeter.  Sorry I should've made it clearer